# Regex: Matching a character and excluding it from the results?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find the first word of every paragraph using a regex in JavaScript. I am doing so with the following:

```
function getFirstWordInParagraph(content) {
  return content.match(/\n\S+/gi);
}
```

The problem here is I cannot figure how to *match* the new line character, but exclude it from the result. Is this possible with a JavaScript regex?

*Note: the function does not account for the first word of the first paragraph.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a special construct for "position at the start of a line": The `^` [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (if you set the `MULTILINE` option):

```
function getFirstWordInParagraph(content) {
  return content.match(/^\S+/gm);
}
```

You don't need the `i` option since nothing in your regex is case-sensitive.

This solution will also find the word at the very start of the string.

Comment: This also solves the problem of not working for the first paragraph.